# How can I filter a DatGrid that's using Outlook COMobjects collection as it's ItemsSource?

Tags: c#, wpf, outlook-addin, com-interop

I have a WPF DataGrid with `ItemSource` as the user selected `Outlook.Folder`.
The DataGrid columns' values are bound to the properties of the bound `Outlook.Folder.Items`. It also has TextBoxes used to filter the respective fields.

To filter the data I created a `ICollectionView`, then using the `TextChanged` event of the TextBox, compare the `FullName` property to the `TextBox.Text`...

```
` ICollectionView FilterView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(KontaktGrid.Items);`

`FilterView.Filter = o =>
      {
        Outlook.ContactItem contact = o as Outlook.ContactItem;
        if (contact.CompanyName.ToUpper().Contains(filterBox.Text.ToUpper()))
            return true;
         return false;
      };`
```

This worked fine on my small sample of contacts, the problem arises with large numbers here is the error message....

> The number of items that can be opened simultaneously has been limited by the server administrator.

So I tried including `Marshal.ReleaseComObject()` under the false condition for my above `if()`

```
`else{
      Marshal.ReleaseComObject(contact/o);
      return false;
      }`
```

alas...

> COM object that has been separated from its underlying RCW cannot be used.

I understand that this is due to the code still using the related object.

Finally, I have tried to get the cell contents value to use as comparison, which in turn I would prefer due to the long read time for accessing each object.
Using

```
`DataGridRow row = DataGrid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(contact/o) 
KontaktGrid.Columns[column].GetCellContent(row);`
```

trying both `o` and its casted counterpart as arguments.

This works in another part of my code, retrieving a CheckBox I use as part of the same DataGrid to show whether an Item is selected or not. In the problem case it has so far only returned null's

I'm stumped.

Comment: Tough cookies.  COM tries to pretend there is nothing special about an object that lives inside another process.  Very convenient abstraction, until it is not.  Add WPF spackle to make it completely unobvious how many of those objects you create and you've got a server burning core to try to keep up with an admin that says "no more".  Only real way to get ahead is to strictly separate the two, turn a COM object into a .NET object as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Never ever loop through all items in a folder. You wouldn't run a SQL query without a WHERE clause, would you?

For queries, always use [Items.Find/FindNext](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.items.find) or [Items.Restrict](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.items.restrict). To retrieve a few items without opening them all (again, don't do that for all items in a folder), use `MAPIFolder.GetTable()`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Outlook.Folder.GetTable

Comment: Thanks Dmitry, this is certainly a push in the right direction.